# TargetServer state at jSCSI

Tags: iscsi

I am starting a TargetServer of jSCSI (http://jscsi.org/bundles/target/apidocs/org/jscsi/target/TargetServer.html) and I want to know how to check if it is initiated successfuly, than I can proceed doing other things.

Does anyone know how to check it?

Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

on linux you can install open-iscsi (the initiator) and check if the target is available to connect.

```
iscsiadm -m discovery -t sendtargets -p 127.0.0.1
```